# How can I recover old version of apk from Google Play Store

Tags: android, apk, google-play

Google Play store apparently keeps old versions of my app .apk file going back forever.  Is there any way I can recover one of those old versions?

I do have everything versioned and tagged, so it shouldn't be too difficult to restore that version of the source code and rebuild the apk file from there.  But I was wondering if there was an easier way to get it.

Comment: I don't know how you're going to get your source code from the APK, but add yourself to Alpha testing, Press "Switch to advanced mode" and move over the old APK to Alpha. Then just download it as normal: It won't disturb your users. You'll probably need a rooted device to take the APK out of the data directory, but I'm not entirely sure so I don't want to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

AStupidNoob answered your question but on a side note. You should really start using [git](http://git-scm.com/) for version control. You can use [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) for free online private git projects to avoid being in a similar situation in the future. If you then remember to [tag](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/02/03/tagging.html) your git versions before releases you'll have an even easier time going back in code.

Comment: There are situation where you DO need actual APK, not the source from which it was made.

Comment: @f470071 That is all great but if you use git correctly you would tag your code every time you put up a new release to play. That way the generated apk will also be pushed as android studio puts it in root of the project.